# SSRS - modify PageName using pagebreaks/group by elements

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-2008-r2, page-break

I have an SSRS report that has one Tablix, it is grouped based on a field 'venue'

[image]

It has a checkbox for 'Page break options' Between each instance of the group.

[image]

So each venue has its own page of data however `PageName` is set to one value under properties.

[image]

Is there a way to automate each page/instance of the venue to be more dynamic.

Comment: PageName can be an expression can't it?

Comment: @DaleK yes, but i'm not sure how to use the groupby element part of the expression

Comment: The expression builder helps you pick data from the dataset.

Comment: @DaleK right, except i'm not sure how to pick group by element

Comment: The group by element is just a column in your dataset right?

Comment: yes it is, when I use the field like this `=Fields!venue.Value` it still only picks the first one and repeats it on each page. When I use it like this `First(Fields!venue.Value, "Master_Data_Set")` it does the same.  I tried doing this ` `First(Fields!venue.Value, "venue")` where venue was the group by name and that didn't even allow me to deploy

Comment: Well yes, it is the "Page Name" so it will display it on every page. You need to show us exactly what you want it to display.

Comment: @DaleK I want it to display the venue name, each page is broken out by a venue, there are maybe 12, the report is grouped by them. That is why I posed this question as how do i use the group by value for the name. Basically if the venue name is Metropolitan Museum of Art that should be the label, the next venue name is New York Transit museum then it should say that on the next page, and so on. Each page is grouped by the venue name and that is what I want to display.

Comment: Using then venue name field in the pagename spot should work.

Comment: @DaleK I wish it was, its giving met the same (first) venue name on all the page, even when i build it like this =Fields!venue.Value. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know, its certainly worked for me, but it might be something subtle which I don't know off the top of my head. Sorry.

Comment: Set the PageName on the Group, not on the table. Select your Group and the go to Properties -> Group -> PageName.

Comment: @HannoverFist sorry for being dense, when I click on the group and select group properties, i see genera, page break, sorting, visibility, filters, variables, advanced and none of them show pageName. Where do I go for this exactly

Comment: Sorry, I meant the properties window pane, not the properties pop up box.

Comment: @HannoverFist I found it, and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Click the Row Group at the bottom to toggle the "Tablix Member" properties.
Then you can see the PageName in Group section.
On your case, PageName  =Fields!venue.value

Answer (score 0):

Pick `Expression` at the `PageName`,

```
=First(Fields!venue.Value, "dataset")
```